# Should you create a separate node.js file to handle get requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a node server that delivers static webpages as well as dynamic content. The dynamic content is served when there are queries along with the request. Is it best practice to handle all requests with the same `server.js` file or should I reroute it to another `someName.js` file?

Comment: When to break code into multiple files is entirely a matter of opinion and depends entirely upon the specific code and code design philosophy.  There is no blanket general guideline that can be described without seeing ANY of your code.  Too many  files, each with a few lines of code in them, creates as many readability challenges as cramming too much in one file.  So, it depends upon the actual code.  As your question stands here, it's not really one that can be answered on stackoverflow as it doesn't contain enough detail about your specific project to offer specific advice.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the user nd readability in my opinion I prefer to know what exactly things are doing
Like if I don't know abt the project and see it the first time I should understand what exactly it's purpose is. I follow a modular project
Suppose you have to do calculation, registration and etc

I will create folders as pery module

```
 Calculation
----calculation-controller.js
----calculation-helper.js
 ----calculation-queries.js
 ----calculation-routes.js
```

So each file inside a module holds a purpose and you can create N number of files and just give it a reasonable name.